After decompiling APK, BuildConfig.java values are accessible even with ProGuard and R8 enabled
I have an Android app where I’m trying to protect sensitive information, such as APPLICATION_ID, VERSION_CODE, and other constants stored in BuildConfig.java. Even though I have enabled ProGuard and R8 in my release build, when I decompile the APK, I can still see the BuildConfig values in the decompiled code.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Enabled ProGuard and R8 in the build.
Added ProGuard rules to obfuscate the code.
Even with these configurations, the BuildConfig values (like APPLICATION_ID, VERSION_NAME, etc.) are still accessible when the APK is decompiled.
Questions:
Is there any way to obfuscate or hide the BuildConfig values so they’re not easily accessible?
If storing sensitive data in BuildConfig is not secure, what are the best practices for securing these types of values in an Android app?
Can ProGuard or R8 be used to further obfuscate or protect BuildConfig?
I’d appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to better secure my app, especially when it comes to BuildConfig exposure.

"sensitive information, such as APPLICATION_ID, VERSION_CODE" -- neither of those can be considered to be sensitive. Their values are visible to others, regardless of what you do with BuildConfig, as they are part of the data published about your app via PackageManager. The application ID will even be published online via the Play Store, should you be planning on distributing your app that way.

version name and application id are both used and found in your manifest after your app is compiled and that is all readable upon a decompile (app store reads those things from the manifest as well as android PackageManager). They are not really sensitive information

@CommonsWare Thank you for reply ,You are right actually i got this as a vulnerability from security tems. It is resolved by progaurd now.
